# Connecting to yahoo email with IMAP4 MailSystem.NET

Tags: c#, email, imap, yahoo

I try to connect to mail yahoo account from C# using net/imap MailSystem.NET.
But I get error *Stack OverFlow* on `imap.Login command`

Anybody tries to connect to Yahoo! Mail and had some experiences about it with MailSystem.NET ?

Here's my working code.

```
Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client();
imap.ConnectSsl("imap.mail.yahoo.com", 993);
imap.Login("login@yahoo.com", "PWD");
imap.Command("capability");
```

Comment: try with `imap.Login("login", "PWD")`, without `@yahoo.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use [ImapX](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b2521818-5a75-4295-8e67-97712ca3073d)

I used it an manage to access Gmail yahoo etc.

BTW- were you able to connect to another mail server like Gmail.com?

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I can download ImapX (HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.). I'm looking for a solution to connect either POP or IMAP
For now I have tested the IMAP connection on yahoo.

Comment: please see the following:http://abramovi.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/connecting-to-email-account-and-fetch.html