# How to read mail content through c# console application

Tags: c#, console-application, imap, yahoo-mail

```
MailRepository rep = new MailRepository("imap.mail.yahoo.com", 993, true, @"xxxxx@yahoo.com", "*******");
foreach (Message email in rep.GetUnreadMails("Inbox"))
{
    //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("<p>{0}: {1}</p><p>{2}</p>", email.From, email.Subject, email.BodyHtml.Text));
    Console.WriteLine(email.From);
    Console.WriteLine(email.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine(email.BodyHtml.Text);
    if (email.Attachments.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (MimePart attachment in email.Attachments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("<p>Attachment: {0} {1}</p>", attachment.ContentName, attachment.ContentType.MimeType));
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code, which is used to read mail content. It's working fine when i tryed for gmail port, but while going for yahoo or some other. It's not allowing me to read the mail throwing exception. Is there any other source . Please guide me

Comment: **What are the details of the exception it is throwing?**

Comment: some time unhandled exception and some times user and password are in-correct

Answer (score 0):

**First**, check your credentials are correct.

**Second**, put a try catch in the constructor to see if you can get more info about the unhandled exception:

```
public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
{
  try {
    if (ssl) {
      Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
    }
    else {
      Client.Connect(mailServer, port);
    }
  Client.Login(login, password);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     //Check the exception details here
  }
}
```

**Third**, the origin of the `MailRepository` class appears to be from [here](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/reading-mails-using-imap-and-mailsystem-net/) that uses the `Imap4Client` implementation which others have complained doesn't work with Yahoo:
[Connecting to yahoo email with IMAP4 MailSystem.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868875/connecting-to-yahoo-email-with-imap4-mailsystem-net)

The accepted answer recommends using [ImapX 2 - crossplatform IMAP library for .NET](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b2521818-5a75-4295-8e67-97712ca3073d) to handle GMail, Yahoo, etc.

Comment: thanks @ jeremy Thompson, i had try catch in my code, here only i neglected . I'll try with this reference